# Simple SWT Alert Message with custom icon?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface, messagebox

Im new to SWT, making a GUI and I just want to give an alert message after the user clicking "OK" button. Like "Your parameters are wrong" with an error icon preferably and "Your parameters are correct" with a **check** icon preferably. I did a little bit searching and it can be possible with `MessageBox()` but it doesnt have check or tick icon, I also don't want to bother creating a custom image and then applying it to the dialog. With `MessageBox()` I have to create a new MessageBox object, set the text and then open the text... Isn't there a simple, one line solution for this like in Swing? `StaticClass.showmsg(type,"String");` for example? If possible I would like to avoid JFace because thats another library and I got tons of errors with JFace, can't be that hard... This is also what I got with `MessageBox()`. Doesn't look ethic.

[image: Message box example]

Edit: I added jface and jface also doesnt have a check icon(MessageDialog) so looks like there is no other chance I will have to add the check icon on my own but how?
My current warning message:

```
MessageDialog.openWarning(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Warning", "Input parameters are wrong!")
```

I wished there was a `MessageDialog.openOK()`, but there isnt so how can I insert my own icon into these messages?

Comment: Would JOptionPane suit your needs?

Comment: @IdusOrtus I will still try to continue with Jface but if it doesnt work then I will use JOptionPane. The JOption pane error/info message comes directly to the center of the screen but the application is on the left upper corner so it doesnt look nice, can I somehow make it appear exactly on the application?

Comment: You could try specifying the application frame as the first argument when invoking showMessageDialog() , or whichever JOptionPane method you decide on. Google joptionpane set position for other options.

Comment: @IdusOrtus I don't have a frame, I have a shell.

Answer (score 2):

The SWT MessageBox uses the native message dialog of the OS/window system (at least on Windows). There is no predefined *check* image for the `MessageBox` in SWT.

For an *informational* message like 'Your parameters are ok', `SWT.ICON_INFORMATION` is provided and  `ICON_ERROR` for - well - error messages.

If that doesn't suit your needs you can either reach out to JFace or write your own message dialog in pure SWT. If you opt for JFace, use the `MessageDialog` for standard dialogs like error, info, warning, etc. or use the `IconAndMessageDialog` if you need more control over the dialog contents.

Comment: `MessageDialog` might be a better option.

Comment: I added the missing jars now it works but requiring jars other than the jface jar itself I dont like... Anyway now the warning message works with jface but on the internet I found limited examples, do you know somewhere I can look and create elegant error/info/OK(**check**) dialogs?

Comment: I couldnt find anything with a check icon so decided to add my own icon just for the "check", how can I do that? I updated my question.

Comment: Hi Rüdiger I switched to jface could you please give an example with `IconAndMessageDialog` for my case?

Comment: @Anarkie see the `MessageDialog` it is based on `IconAndMessageDialog` and gives a good enough example how it can be used..

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain how you would go about finding the position of the console window (which you would need in order to align a pane to it) but if you're concerned about the overall appearance of your application you're likely best off using *only* one or the other to maintain consistency.

The following may be of use if you opt for a GUI.

If the data you are collecting is **not** simple you might want to take a look at [NetBeans Swing GUI Builder (Matisse)](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) . Folks have various opinions on builders but I feel the NetBeans one is a fair way to become familiar with Swing and you can't beat the price. Take an hour or so, walk through the basic tutorials, and you'll be designing simple (albeit vanilla) GUIs in no time.

If the data you are collecting is simple you could use showInputDialog(). Here's a simple, far from perfect, drop-down example. If you provide more information regarding the data you are collecting I can provide a different example.

```
String response;
String[] possibleValues = { "a Pony", "a Job", "World Peace"};

JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Choose one", "Select Something",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
        possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);

response = String.format("You desire %s\n", possibleValues);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
```

Simple examples of JOptionPane message windows, with custom icons from URL:

```
public void foo() throws MalformedURLException
{

    ImageIcon failIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://cdn0.iconfinder" +
            ".com/data/icons/star-wars/512/darth_vader-32.png"));
    ImageIcon okIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.fimfiction-static" +
            ".net/images/avatars/98207_32.jpg?1373627869"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parameters are incorrect.", "Derp",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, failIcon);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parameters are correct.", "Rejoice",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, okIcon );
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Idus thanks for your answer, I found lots of icon examples for JOptionPane but like you said I decided to stick to one GUI widget and that will be SWT, because the alert message comes slower compared to SWT. So Im looking for a way to insert my own icon into SWT/JFace for `MessageDialog.openWarning(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Warning", "Input parameters are wrong!")`